# Autoupdate of the primary key in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I created the table using SQLiteOpenHelper the image of the table i created is given below  [image]

After this I delete the first row from the table and now my table looks like this[image]

You can see that the id is now starting with 2.
So my problem is when I delete the first row the id first column goes to 2
Please help me to solve this issue . i want a table looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Could you tell us why you want the Id to change when deleting? Problem with this is, that if you get a bigger table like say 1000 rows, then you'd have to change ALL the Id's whenever you remove one row. It's gonna be a lot of work and might possible be a performance issue in the end. Maybe you need to re-think, you're overall design instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can see that the id is now start with 2. So my problem is when I
>   delete the first row the id first column goes to 2 Please help me to
>   solve this issue

There is no problem with id value. If you are using autoincrement or not this is normal behaviour. In the case of autoincrement has internal iterator and it hasn't "memory".

**So imagine this scenario:** You have two rows with id 1, 2.

*What will happen when you will delete first row?*

In db will remain one row with id 2 but if you will insert next row, this row will be automatic have value id with 3 not deleted 1 also if you will delete first row, second row won't change value to 1.

In the other case if you are not using **autoincrement** this is possible(only make it programatically) but i think this approach is not effective. If you will have for example milion records, every row's id should be changed? This is sick.

So here is really not problem but normal behaviour.

Comment: but after deletion  i want get the result as third image shown above. is this possible ?

Comment: @Nithinlal no, it's not possible. Read my answer i wrote that this is possible change ids programatically but it's not good approach because in the case of many tows this operation will consume much of time and especially for devices it's not effective because they have limited memory, battery etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably one of the following:

- Your ID field is simply called `id`, whereas Android uses the conventional name `_id` (as a Java constant, [`BaseColumns._ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID)).
- The ID field should be of type `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: I think the first bullet here is a convention and not a rule as such.

Comment: I set the id as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. But i don't get the result